# Chrome and Firefox exhibit different handling of an "invalid" DST time

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dst

Smallest example:

```
var test = new Date();
test.setMonth(3);
test.setDate(3);
test.setHours(2);
test.getUTCHours()`
```

On Firefox I get "7" and Chrome gives me "8" (what I consider the correct answer).

DST is approaching and I've been tasked with fixing various issues with change in our javascript. I'm not sure how to handle this though. The time is moving forward 1 hour so at we will go from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00 skipping 2am completely. The problem is we have multiple datetime pickers that have no concepts of this (and that's ok) and so you can still select 2am times. I would expect when I construct a date from a 2am time that it would get pushed to 3am so 2:05 becomes 3:05. Chrome handles this just fine however Firefox appears to push it back to 1:05. The UTC are off by one hour however when you format with a timezone it will appear as 1:05.

How can I work around this? I think the answer is just "momentjs" but I want to understand why this is different.

Comment: Isn't DST on the 13th?

Comment: The result of the above depends entirely on the host system time zone setting. For the vast majority of the world's population, 02:00 on 3 April has no great significance.

Comment: JavaScript time is based on the Browser time, which is usually based on the Client's OS time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a phone so ill answer in more detail later, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989484/eliminating-javascript-daylight-saving-time-gap-a-cross-browser-solution/28997705#28997705 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/29453582/634824

Comment: @PHPglue It's on the 13th for the USA but I'm testing for Mexico (America/Mexico_City) (I should have pointed that out). The same behaviour can be observed for the 13th if you computer is set in a US timezone.

Comment: @JoshStrange - Yep, [you have a bit more time then](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/mexico/mexico-city).  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson A little more time kind of for some of the issues but I've got to have my fixed tested and deployed by the 13th because they also fix assumptions made by people before me that CST = America/Chicago and all our Mexican customers have "CST" timezone (which isn't a real thing). So on the 13th all their times will be off unless I get in the changes to migrate them all to America/Mexico_City

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  The Spring Forward DST transition will create a gap of *invalid* local time.  JavaScript will either advance it forward it backward, by the amount of the gap.  Which direction it goes is not defined in the ECMAScript specification, and thus different browsers do it differently.  IMHO, moving *forward* makes the most logical sense (since time moves forward), but some feel that using "standard" time should be prefered.

For the Fall Back DST transition, there is a period of overlapping local time, where a local time may be *ambiguous*.  JavaScript will either map it to the first instance (daylight time), or the second instance (standard time).  Again, some feel that "standard" time should be prefered, but it makes more logical sense to go in the order that time actually occurs - which means choosing the *daylight* instance.

Here's how the landscape currently looks for desktop browsers:

[image: Spring Forward Browser Behavior]

[image: Fall Back Browser Behavior]

I've updated these charts many times over the last few years, as it even within browsers it has changed between versions.  The first versions I made for [my Pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals) looked quite different.  Many of the browsers have flipped from one side of the behavior to the other.  So be careful about making any assumptions - older browsers could very well have differences from this chart.  I also didn't show the vast array of mobile web browsers out there.

Now you asked about how to deal with this problem.  Unfortunately, there aren't a lot of good options.  You mentioned moment.js, which is indeed a great library for dates and times - but since it presently relies on the `Date` object under the hood, it does not solve this particular problem.  It inherits whatever behavior the browser has.  (This is a known issue, and we're working on it.)

### Update

I previously had written some functions to show how to work around the problem.  You can still find these if you review the edit history.  Unfortunately, I made one critical mistake with the `isShiftedForward` and `isShiftedBackward` methods.  Though they returned `true` if a timestamp had been shifted, they also returned true (incorrectly) when given a valid timestamp immediately adjacent to the transition.  (That is, in the hour following when shifting forward, or the hour preceding when shifting backward.)

Therefore, I've removed these functions from the answer.  There's no way to avoid this without knowing the original values that created the `Date` object. They can't work from the `Date` object alone.

Comment: I don't think "invalid" local times exist. The issue is how to interpret the timezone when the supplied data is ambiguous, e.g. a time when two timezones (such as PST and PDT) *might* both apply such as 2016-03-13 at 02:30 in Los Angeles. However, including the timezone, say PST, converts unequivocally to 03:30 PDT in the same way you might convert between any two other timezones. So if the timezone is always included, there's no ambiguity. The concept can be extended so that when parsing a string, apply the supplied timezone offset to the parsed values and use UTC methods to create the Date.

Comment: Thank you for those charts, they were very helpful and confirmed I wasn't going crazy!

Comment: @RobG - Because the clocks tick from 01:59 to 03:00 on that day, any time in the 2:00 hour is indeed invalid.  There are many well established APIs that use the term "invalid" to describe a time in this gap.  I did not invent that term.

Comment: I think you missed my point. The issue is in the algorithm to convert an ambiguous (rather than "invalid") time to something that isn't. If the time zone is provided, then there is no ambiguity. IT is full of misleading terms (e.g. "locale" to describe personal preferences), appeals to tradition don't work on me. ;-)

Comment: Oh, but then that all depends on *how* the time zone was provided.  If it's a fixed offset, then sure - no ambiguity whatsoever.  But if it's just "Pacific Time", or even "America/Los_Angeles", then there is indeed ambiguity in the fall, and a gap that is "invalid" or "missing" or "not measured on local clocks" or whatever term you prefer.

Comment: Besides, the functions I supplied don't use those terms anyway, nor do they make an ambiguous time any less ambiguous.  They just normalize the behavior so it's consistent across all implementations.  Consistent to *my* preferences, sure - I'll give you that.  But I have found from experience that this particular set of alignments fit most of the scenarios.  (I do know of a few that would prefer the other side of the fall transition, but none that work well with shifting backward in the spring.)

Comment: I do enjoy these debates with you though! ;)

Comment: @JoshStrange - I just realized a critical mistake in the algorithm, so I removed the functions and updated with an explanation.  Sorry!

Comment: @MattJohnson Don't worry, I ended up being able to vastly simplify all my logic by reaching into the plugins I was using to grab year/month/day/hour/minute/seconds and feed that data into momentjs instead of asking for a date object from the plugin. Moment exhibits the (what I consider correct) pushing forward of 2:XX -> 3:XX and it works (obviously) in both FF and Chrome (and the rest) so I'm good now! Your charts were very helpful and really what I needed as my googling turned up very little on this exact issue.

Comment: It's still inconsistent in FF even with moment.  We're working on that.  You may want to review https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2618.  Sorry i don't have a better answer for you at this time.